# Collection Routes with post

Tags: ruby-on-rails

To add a route to the collection `photo` I write :

```
resources :photos do
  collection do
    post 'myaction'
  end
end
```

and this generates a path `/photos/myaction`. However, in case of the `create` action, Rails generates a path `/photos` not `/photos/create`. How can I configure my route.rb so that I could use `photos_path` instead of `myaction_photos_path` (just like the `create` action)?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It's against rails convention.

Comment: I just want to create a new action, say bulk create or something else, that posts data. Then within my controller I want to process the data and return to another page. What I need is only a POST action, say `bulkcreate`. I do not need a path `photos/bulkcreate`. I just need to specify the controller name and action name in my form. I don't think this is against Rails' convention. After all, `create` action works similarly.

Comment: In other words, why doesn't Rails generate `create_photos_path` for the `create` action?